# Method & Array, Swapping number in index

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, indexing

Hi I wrote a method/array I am trying to make my code swap the second number and second to last number in the index but the only number that's is swapping was my second number and my last, if you could help a newbie I would be very thank full.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n=====================\n");
    DisplayArray(A); 
    Console.WriteLine("\nSwapping Second and Second to last Number");
    SwapSecAndSecLast(A);
    DisplayArray(A);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void SwapSecAndSecLast(int[] array)
{
    int temp = array[1];
    array[1] = array[array.Length - 1];
    array[array.Length - 1] = temp;
}

static void DisplayArray(int[] array)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n=====================\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0} ",array[i]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\n=====================\n");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second to last is

```
array[array.Length - 2];
```

not

```
array[array.Length - 1];
```

...  since arrays are zero-based. However, you should check if it contains enough elements.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are 0 based, so array[array.Length - 1] is the last element in the array.  If you want the second to last, use array[array.Length - 2]